# Playing at FC2024 with Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3-15ARH05 PROBLEM

Tags: ea-sports-fc-mobile

I am experiencing difficulties playing at the latest fersion of EASports FC2024 with my notebook, which is Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3-15ARH05. Is this still a powerful enough notebook or should I purchase a more potent one?